# Uppercase last n characters of every line in a wordlist regexp

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, word-list

I'm looking for a way to uppercase the last n characters of every line in a wordlist, using regular expression. Example with n=3:

Input:

```
thisisatest
uppercasethelast3characters
```

Desired output:

```
thisisatEST
uppercasethelast3charactERS
```

Comment: What would the expected output be if the line only contained 2 characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this GNU `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/^\(.*\)\(.\{3\}\)$/\1\U\2/' file
```

With extended regex:

```
sed -r 's/^(.*)(.{3})$/\1\U\2/' file
```

**Test:**

```
$ sed -e 's/^\(.*\)\(.\{3\}\)$/\1\U\2/' file
thisisatEST
uppercasethelast3charactERS
```

Comment: @crendaline75 - I've deleted my answer now as I don't want you to change but I'm just very curious: what was it that made you pick `sed -e 's/^\(.*\)\(.\{3\}\)$/\1\U\2/' file` over the functionally equivalent but more concise `sed 's/.\{3\}$/\U&/' file` I had posted?

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged perl, I'm posting a perl solution...

```
# with RegEx
perl -nle '/(.*)(.{3})$/; print $1 . uc $2;' file.txt
# formatted with n at the end
cat file.txt | perl -nle 'print $1 . uc $2 if /(.*)(.{3})$/;'

# or without RegEx
perl -nle '$n=3; print substr($_,0,-$n).uc substr($_,length($_)-$n);' file.txt
# formated with n at the end
cat file.txt| perl -nle 'print substr($_,0,-$n).uc substr($_,length($_)-$n) if $n=3;'
```

The `substr` solution will be a *lot* faster than doing regex captures.

Answer (score 0):

Without the `\U` feature (that is a GNU feature), it's a bit less handy:

```
sed -e 'h;s/.\{3\}$//;x;s/.*\(.\{3\}\)/\1/;y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/;H;g;s/\n//;' file
```

details:

```
h              # copy the pattern space into the buffer space
s/.\{3\}$//    # remove the 3 last characters (in the pattern space)
x              # exchange the pattern space and the buffer space
s/.*\(.\{3\}\)/\1/ # remove all characters except the three last
# translate lower case to upper case letters 
y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/
H  # append the pattern space to the buffer space
g  # replace the pattern space with the buffer space
s/\n// # remove the newline character
```

Comment: A simpler solution might be:  `sed '/.\{3\}$/!b;s//\n&/;h;y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/;H;g;s/\n.*\n//' file`

Comment: @potong: This solution works too, but I don't see in what it is more simple.